# how to change to new line in case environment of Equations

Tags: equations

I am try to using the newline symbol to make `"a="` in the first line and then the following in the newline, however it does not work.

```
\begin{equation}
 a =\\
\begin{case}
 3\\
 2\\
\end{case}
\end{equation}
```

the formula shows like the following:
[image]

I want the `a=` in the first line and new line to `3 and 2`, can anyone help me ? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I would propose to use the `align` environment:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 a =&\nonumber\\
    &\begin{cases}
        3\\
        2
     \end{cases}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: The two lines are aligned at the `&` character.

Comment: this *is* what has been requested, but i do find it rather peculiar.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for your comment, how would you do that?

Comment: actually, you've done what was asked for.  if it's to be in separate lines, then `equation` won't work, since that can handle only one line, unless something like `split` is applied.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a stack.  Note that the equation number is aligned with the original baseline (if that is desired).  In this case, I provided a 5pt gap to the underset.

Based on comment by the OP, I have EDITED the answer to provide several different alignment options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\def\stackalignment{l}
 \stackunder[5pt]{a =}{
\begin{cases}
 3\\
 2\\
\end{cases}}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\def\stackalignment{l}
 a \stackunder[5pt]{{}={}}{{}\mathrel{
\begin{cases}
 3\\
 2\\
\end{cases}}}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 a = \stackunder[5pt]{}{%
\begin{cases}
 3\\
 2\\
\end{cases}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, however, is there any way to move the curly bracket to the left and align with a?

Comment: @sweetyBaby I reread your comment an now have provided several alignment possibilities for the stacks.